# Qt: How to set "?" button for a QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

In a QWidget like QLabel, how can we set a "?" button, such that when clicked (or hovered) it should show some help text.

Comment: Look at `Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to show help when hover QWidget: setToolTip(QString) and setToolTipDuration(int).
If you want a "?" button, just implement your own QWidget. Then via ui designer or directly in your code add QPushButton and QLabel on layout, and show your QLabel with help text in position of cursor when clicked(). Something like this:

```
{
// Constructor
...
    m_mainLabel = new QLabel("Main text");
    m_button = new QPushButton("?");
    m_helpLabel = new QLabel("Help text");
    connect(m_button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),
            this, SLOT(slotShowOrHideHelpLabel(bool)));
    QHBoxLayout *hBoxLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    hBoxLayout->addWidget(m_mainLabel);
    hBoxLayout->addWidget(m_button);
    setLayout(hBoxLayout);
}

void slotShowOrHideHelpLabel(bool showHelpLabel)
{
    if (showHelpLabel)
    {
        m_helpLabel->show();
        m_helpLabel->move(QCursor::pos());
    }
    else
    {
        m_helpLabel->hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Instead of creating a helpLabel, on the "?" button click, I am doing setToolTip() and setWhatsThis() for the main label. But somehow the tool tip and whats this are not coming up. How to enable them on click event?

Comment: You can use eventFilter to process click event on your main Label without implementing custom class. And in handler of click event create and show helpLabel with text that you set in toolTip or whatsThis. As I understand, toolTip, WhatsThis, statusTip are the properties to hold information. You can use it for your purposes, for example, show in a label when clicked))

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use QMenu instead of QPushButton + QLabel.

```
// Constructor
setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
connect(this, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)), this, SLOT(slotCustomMenu(QPoint)));

// slotCustomMenu(QPoint)
QMenu menu(this);
menu.addAction(this->toolTip());
menu.addAction(this->whatsThis());
menu.exec(QCursor::pos());
```